# How to pass post params to PDFKit instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdfkit

I currently use the pdf middleware with pdfkit to generate a larger PDF document.  It works great but takes some time to process so I have moved it to a background process performed by Sidekiq.

I would like to call PDFKit.new(url), but I can't use a params string because it's too long (I was using post before which worked fine).

I have tried using render_anywhere but this has a number of problems including errors when pdfkit attempts to generate the footer, which is a url.

Is there any way I can set the post params on PDFKit?